# Верстка элемента в таблице

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image]

На изображении имеется голубая полоска с текстом *Просмотров/Предложений 24/14 ...*. Данная полоска находится в каждой строке таблицы и должна по длине равняться расстоянию между правой границей первой ячейки и левой границей последней. Текст в столбце *Наименование* может иметь различную ширину.

Как ее можно сверстать?

Адаптивность не нужна. Таблица фиксированная 1000px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
 border-spacing: 0;
}
table thead tr th{
    background: #F7DF89;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C56636;
}
table tr th,
table tr td{
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    padding: 10px;
}
.td-blue{
    background: #DFEEF5;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>th</th> 
        </tr>     
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">td</td>
            <td>td</td>
            <td>td</td>
            <td>td</td>
            <td>td</td>
            <td>td</td>
            <td rowspan="2">td</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td class="td-blue" colspan="5">td</td>                       
       </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```